# Python train and load Tensorflow / Keras models

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, neural-network

Hey I want to save and load my trained model but got some issues with doing so.

Within the training python script, after training the model, it does a prediction for the string "nobody likes you" and it gives me the result "Spam: 96.0959%" which is correct.

However when I try it with the python test code, where I load the same model with the same weight, for the same text it gives me a complete different reading for example "Approve: 49%".

So I am not sure but I think I somehow save or load the trained model the wrong way.

All I want to achieve is, to train a model first, save that model and be able to do text predictions using that trained model, without the need to retrain it everytime.

A snippet from my Training code:

```
# Convert labels to numerical format
label_to_index = {
    'Approve': 0,
    'Spam': 1,
    ...
}

# Tokenization and Padding
tokenizer = Tokenizer()
tokenizer.fit_on_texts(posts)
num_unique_words = len(tokenizer.word_index)
tokenizer.num_words = num_unique_words
sequences = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(posts)
max_sequence_length = 7500;

X = pad_sequences(sequences, maxlen=max_sequence_length)
y = np.array([label_to_index[label] for label in labels])

# Split data into training and testing sets
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=42)

# Neural Network Architecture
model = Sequential()
vocab_size = tokenizer.num_words
model.add(Embedding(input_dim=vocab_size, output_dim=50, input_length=max_sequence_length))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(128, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(19, activation='softmax'))

# Model Compilation
model.compile(loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])

# Model Training
history = model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=10, batch_size=32, validation_data=(X_test, y_test))

model_architecture = model.to_json()
with open('model_architecture_old.json', 'w') as json_file:
    json_file.write(model_architecture)

model.save_weights('model_weights_old.h5')
```

And I load and test the saved weight and json doing so:

```
# Load the model architecture from the JSON file
with open('model_architecture_old.json', 'r') as json_file:
    model_architecture = json_file.read()

# Create a new model instance using the loaded architecture
loaded_model = model_from_json(model_architecture)

# Load the saved weights from the checkpoint file
loaded_model.load_weights('model_weights_old.h5')

# Compile the model before using it (same compilation as during training)
loaded_model.compile(loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])

# Get user input for testing
num_texts = int(input("Enter the number of texts you want to test: "))
texts = []
for i in range(num_texts):
    text = input(f"Enter text {i+1}: ")
    texts.append(text)

# Tokenization and Padding
tokenizer = Tokenizer()
tokenizer.fit_on_texts(texts)  # Replace 'texts' with your text data
sequences = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(texts)
max_sequence_length = 7500;
X = pad_sequences(sequences, maxlen=max_sequence_length)

# Make predictions using the loaded model
predictions = loaded_model.predict(X)
```